# Promise.all raises TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm returning a list of promises from a function, and I need to get the values of that array. Therefore, I'm using the `Promise.all` function. But this doesn't work very well for me. I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at new MySearchesTable (my-searches-table.js:162)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:6801)
```

Here's where the error originates from.

```
class MySearchesTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      let data = Promise.all(modelInstance.getSearchHistory()); // Error traceback starts here!
      this.state = {
        selected: [],
        data: data,
        page: 0,
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        open: false,
      };
```

And here's the function that returns a list of promises:

```
  /*
  * Gets searches for logged in user
  */
  this.getSearchHistory = function(){

    let currUserSearches;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
      if(user){
        let uid = user.uid;

        let userRef = database.ref("users/"+uid);

        return userRef.once("value")
        .then( (value) => {
          let currUserSearchesIDs = value.val();
          console.log("currUserSearches:");
          let currUserSearches = currUserSearchesIDs.map( searchID => {
            return database.ref("searches/"+searchID).once("value")
                .then( (value) => {
                  let obj = value.val();
                  obj["id"] = searchID;
                  return obj;
                });
          });
          console.log(currUserSearches);
          resolve(currUserSearches);
        });
      }else{
        reject("Must log in"); // user must log in
      }
      }
    )
    });

  }
```

What is the reason for this error? How can I successfully get a list of the values I have in my database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53270650/1048572

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `Promise.all` expects an `iterable`. You are only returning **1 promise**.

Look:

[image]

In the above example I'm using `Promise.all` and passing a single `Promise` to it. The result of `Promise.resolve(null)` is 1 promise that resolves to null.

The error doesn't occur when you pass an array of `Promise` like:

```
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(null)])
```

That being said, I must point out that you should reconsider your design, because you are not supposed to wait on promises on the constructor. Use `componentDidMount` for that. The first render of your component should have `data` as null, and eventually display a loading indicator. On `componentDidMount`, trigger the data fetching part. Once the data is returned, re-render your component, now with the data already fetched.