# Promise.all error inside async function : undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

in my async function i use `Promise.all`  but for some reason its not defined or something here is the function

```
async function check_available_money() {


    global_browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await global_browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 1100});
    var setting = {'username': 'aa', 'password': 'bb'};


    try {
        await page.goto('https://example.com/login', {timeout: 90000})
            .catch(function (error) {
                    throw new Error(' TIMEOUT 1 ');
                }
            );

        await page.$eval('#username', (el, setting) => el.value = setting.username, setting);
        await page.$eval('#password', (el, setting) => el.value = setting.password, setting);


        console.log(tab_id + ' -> SUMITING LOGIN FORM  ');
        await Promise.all(
            page.$eval('form', form => form.submit()),
            page.waitForNavigation()
        )


        console.log(tab_id + ' -> SUMITING LOGIN FORM DONE !  ');



    }
    catch (e) {

        await page.close();
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

i get error from this part

```
await Promise.all(
            page.$eval('form', form => form.submit()),
            page.waitForNavigation()
        )
```

if i remove `await Promise.all` and just type

```
            await page.$eval('form', form => form.submit());
            await page.waitForNavigation();
```

it works ok

here is error stack

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at check_available_money (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\server.js:115:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:13184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
    at Promise (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:202:56)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:201:12)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:79:75)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:46:31)
    at ElementHandle.$eval (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ElementHandle.js:293:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:13184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:13184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (D:\wamp\www\withdraw\robot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:73:21)
    at <anonymous>
(node:13184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

Comment: does `page.waitForNavigation` require the former call to finish before it becomes available? `Promise.all` isn't the same as awaiting them in order. Promise.all runs them all at once and waits for them all to return or for one to reject before it finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an iterable, not multiple arguments. It tried to iterate your first argument, but that didn't have a `[Symbol.iterator]` method - "*undefined is not a function*". Pass an array:

```
await Promise.all([
    page.$eval('form', form => form.submit()),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
])
```

Comment: thanx that did it